Schema Validation Error on Ubuntu 22.04.4 live server Autoinstall
I've been attempting an automatic installation of Ubuntu 22.04 using the autoinstall.yaml file, which worked fine in Ubuntu 20.04. However, I'm encountering schema validation errors specifically related to the user-data section. Despite following the format closely and ensuring all data types and strings are correctly input, the errors persist.
The message indicates a type mismatch, suggesting that the structure or content of my autoinstall.yaml might not meet the updated schema requirements for the latest Ubuntu version. I've checked for correct string formatting, validated the YAML syntax, and ensured that the SSH keys are continuous single-line strings.
Could someone help identify the potential causes or changes in the autoinstall schema from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 that might be affecting this? Below is a snippet of the error output for reference.
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  timezone: America/Lima
  ssh:
    allow-pw: true
    install-server: true
  identity:
    hostname: hector-pruebas
    password: ""
    username: hector
  user-data:  
    users:
    - name: "hector"
      sudo: "ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"
      shell: "/bin/bash"
      lock_passwd: false
      password: ""
      ssh_authorized_keys:
      - "ssh-rsa ...."

ERROR:
[ERROR] cloudinit.config.schema.SchemaValidationError: Cloud config schema errors: autoinstall.user-data.users.0: {'name': 'username', 'passwd': 'hashed_passwd', ...} is not type 'string'

error image
